# Cant call ajax inside other ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im executing this ajax from select option on change its value and its working.

```
function ambilDataServis() {
var nama_checklist = $("#servis_nama_checklist").val();
var rentang_checklist = $("#servis_rentang_checklist").val();
var jenis_checklist = $("#servis_jenisChecklist").val();
$.ajax({
url: 'script/ambil_data.php',
type: "POST",
data:  {jenis_checklist:jenis_checklist, nama_checklist:nama_checklist, rentang_checklist:rentang_checklist},
success: function(data)
    { 
        $("#halaman_dinamis_servis").css('opacity','1');
        $("#halaman_dinamis_servis").html(data);
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
         $("#halaman_dinamis_servis").css('opacity','0.5');
    }
});
}
```

Then I call this another ajax which is called from another select option inside dynamic content from above ajax script and its not working.

Before above ajax call its working, but after above ajax call its not working

```
$(document).on("change","#non_servis_row_checklist", function(){
var nama_checklist = $("#non_servis_nama_checklist").val();
var rentang_checklist = $("#non_servis_rentang_checklist").val();
var jenis_checklist = $("#non_servis_jenisChecklist").val();
var servis_row_checklist = $("#non_servis_row_checklist").val();
$.ajax({
url: 'script/ambil_row_data.php',
type: "POST",
data:  {jenis_checklist:jenis_checklist, servis_row_checklist:servis_row_checklist, nama_checklist:nama_checklist, rentang_checklist:rentang_checklist},
success: function(data)
    { 
        $("#panelC_non_service_content").css('opacity','1');
        $("#panelC_non_service_content").html(data);
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
         $("#panelC_non_service_content").css('opacity','0.5');
    }
});
});
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<select onchange="ambilDataServis()">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<div id="halaman_dinamis_servis">
   <select id="non_servis_row_checklist">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
   </select>
   <div id="panelC_non_service_content">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: ajax has a failure callback function parameter.  I recommend you look at the results of that as a start.

Comment: I think the problem is that the second ajax script not being called because the real element is no longer there because already replaced by the first ajax call. But i dunno how to fix it.

Comment: good heavens! format your code properly please!

Comment: Why is one ajax call being run within a function and the other is on an element's listener. Maybe make them both functions and see what happens.

Comment: do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Oh i remember now, its working with change everything with function. Actually at first im using all function not inside the "on".

But seems like the problem is after the firts ajax call, i cant get the value from the second select option anymore but the ajax is running.

Comment: Thnx by the way. But it seems its not the real problem. I guess i would ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are calling here as the 3rd parameter.
    $(document).on("change","#non_servis_row_checklist"

I recommend you name the function (not an anonymous one), and then call it manually after assigning the DIV content in the first ajax success (Call it immediately after $("#panelC_non_service_content").html(data);).

This is because I don't believe the onchange function is getting called by you essentially rebuilding the HTML inside the DIV.

Comment: Thnx, the ajax is working now, but seems like its not the problem, i guess i would ask another question.